# for cycle - page stops loading, any alternatives?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, for-loop, cycle

I need to echo array, but the page stops loading. I am running Wordpress.

```
    if($categories)  {
        for ($i=0;$i<count($categories);$i++) {
        echo $categories[$i].", ";
        }
    }
```

I really does not know why. Is there any other way to do that? Or grab array into one string. E.g.

```
$categories[0] = "aaa";
$categories[1] = "bbb";
$string = "aaa, bbb";
```

(Array have unknown number of values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfect for [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), just use it like this:

```
echo implode(", ", $categories);
```

As an example:

```
$categories = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
echo implode(", ", $categories);
```

Output:

```
aaa, bbb, ccc
```